# "Search More..." in my many2one field

Tags: search, listbox, odoo

I want an advanced search when picking an item from many2one listbox. This feature is implemented for 'res.groups' object, for example. I cannot find this feature in /addons.

To be more exact, I define my object

```
class my_child(osv.osv):
    _name = 'my.child'
    _columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Child name'),
    }
my_children()
```

I define a parent which has many2one relation to child object and existing resource object

```
class my_parent(osv.osv):
    _name = 'my.parent'
    _columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Parent name'),
    'child': fields.many2one('my.child', 'Child'),
    'res_group_id': fields.many2one('res.groups', 'Group'),
    }
```

Then I add child and res_group_id to my_parent's xml form view

```
...
<field name="child"/>
<field name="res_group_id"/>
...
```

The res_group_id has "Search More..." option which opens search view but "child" does not.
Please, how do I add "Search More..." option to the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add 5 or more records to your child model. then you will be able to see the 'search more.. '